# Export hive table to .avro file

Tags: sql, hadoop, export, hive

I created an external hive table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE some_hive_table
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/hdfs/path/some_hive_table/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='{json schema here}');
```

I'd like to run some hive queries on it and export that data into an avro file.  I know I can export data like this:

```
INSERT
OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/hdfs/path/avrofileoutput/' 
SELECT * FROM some_hive_table;
```

But I want my output file to be an avro file - not csv.  Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out below option.

insert overwrite table some_hive_table_avro select * from some_hive_table_text;

Comment: but that exports to another hive table.  I'm looking to export to an avro file.  Would there be an underlying avro file that this table creates that would be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes. You can use the underlying .avro file. If you still want it to be single avro file you may try following command..

hadoop fs -cat /<path_to_avro_files>/* > student.avro

Answer (score 5):

You can export any table irrespective of InputStorage as an AVRO file using below command to a Local location or HDFS location.

Starting with Hive 0.11.0

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '<Local directory>'
    STORED AS AVRO SELECT * FROM some_hive_table;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries